# jQuery file input on change not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, html-input

I have bound two separate events for testing, but for whatever reason neither of them are triggering when I select a file. I'm sure I have just not had enough coffee today but it seems to be the correct way of detecting file selection.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="files">
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {

    $("#files").on("change", function() {
        alert("Files changed.");
    });

    $(document).on("change", "#files", function() {
        alert("Files changed.");
    });

});
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/snoapps/66y45hjh/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/66y45hjh/2/

Your second function was correct but the way the functions are nested wouldn't let it execute the way you wanted it to. Take a look at the edit I made to your fiddle.

The javascript code I used was as follows.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("change", "#files", function() {
        alert("Files changed.");
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain the downvote? The code works as it is supposed to.

Comment: This works, what's the point of using the $(function() {}); in the script? (p.s. I don't know who downvoted, it wasn't me)

Comment: `$(function() {});` is just a simplified way of writing out `$('document').ready(function(){});` It's best practice to execute trigger events within it to be sure that the document is fully loaded before a user fires the event

Answer (score 3):

1. It's `$('document').ready(function(){});`
   https://api.jquery.com/ready
2. You don't need your second function

So:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#files").on("change", function() {
        alert("Files changed.");
    });


});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that `on("ready"` became deprecated in 1.8, both answers work for me, but Alex answered first